# cmsis_compiler.h: No such file or directory while compiling Arduino Tensorflow lite library for Arduino Due

Tags: c++, c, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, stm32f1

I am trying to compile the Arduino Tensorflow lite Library example file for Arduino Due board, but at the time of compilation I got error of missing cmsis_compiler.h  file error. I also tried to compile the code for STM32F103C8 board on Arduino version 1.8.12 with the **Arduino_TensorFlowLite at version 2.1.0-ALPHA-precompiled** library but still the same error. Here is the complete error

````
                 from C:\Users\Strange Lab\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src/third_party/gemmlowp/fixedpoint/fixedpoint.h:24,

                 from C:\Users\Strange Lab\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src/tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/reference/add.h:18,

                 from C:\Users\Strange Lab\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src\tensorflow\lite\micro\kernels\cmsis-nn\add.cpp:16:

c:\users\strange lab\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arm-none-eabi-gcc\4.8.3-2014q1\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\4.8.3\bits\c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \

  ^

In file included from C:\Users\Strange Lab\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/cmsis/CMSIS/NN/Include/arm_nnsupportfunctions.h:33:0,

                 from C:\Users\Strange Lab\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/cmsis/CMSIS/NN/Include/arm_nnfunctions.h:163,

                 from C:\Users\Strange Lab\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src\tensorflow\lite\micro\kernels\cmsis-nn\add.cpp:18:

C:\Users\Strange Lab\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite\src/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/cmsis/CMSIS/DSP/Include/arm_math.h:382:28: fatal error: cmsis_compiler.h: No such file or directory

 #include "cmsis_compiler.h"

                            ^

compilation terminated.

Using library Arduino_TensorFlowLite at version 2.1.0-ALPHA-precompiled in folder: C:\Users\Strange Lab\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_TensorFlowLite 
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Generic STM32F103C series.``` 

I can understand that may be the Arduino Due is not officially supported but I think the STM32F103C8 board is supported. So is there anything which I am missing here?
````

Answer (score -1):

I hope you have found an answer yourself since posting this question, but for anyone else fumbling their way in here; it seems like the current tensorflow-lite library (as I'm writing this it is: 2.1.0-APLHA-precompiled) only works with MbedOS-boards (Portenta H7 and Nano 33 BLE).

Hope you could use this answer :D